.exe file created using pyinstaller is not workinng
I am tryng to make an executable file for my app created with pyqt5. I am using pyinstaller to create the dist folder and using this command:
pyinstaller main.py

It runs ok. There ir no error message in the cmd and finishes with an: "5543 INFO: Building COLLECT COLLECT-00.toc completed successfully." (so I asume it is all ok)
Then I modify the .spec file to include icons and resources my app will need. Then I execute
pyinstaller main.spec

to update the changes and then go to the dist folder and double click on my .exe and it stars running but in a fraction of second the cmd closes and I can't see why it is no launching my app (there must be an error message but I can't reach to read it).
I try to launch the .exe file from cmd using "start app.exe" and it is the same! I don't know how to make the cmd still even the app crashes!
This is my .spec file content
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-


a = Analysis(
    ['main.py'],
    pathex=[],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[("resources", "resources"), ("resources.qrc", "."), (r"model\database.db", "model")],
    hiddenimports=[],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    noarchive=False,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    [],
    exclude_binaries=True,
    name='urimare',
    icon=r".\resources\iconosApp\urimareIcono01.ico",
    debug=True,  # set to True to find possible problems
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    console=True,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
)
coll = COLLECT(
    exe,
    a.binaries,
    a.datas,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    name='urimare',
)

This is my custom_table_model module
from PyQt5 import QtCore
import pandas as pd
class CustomTableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, data_source, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)
        self._data_source = data_source

    def data(self, index, role):
        value = self._data_source.iloc[index.row(), index.column()]

        if index.isValid():
            if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole or role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole:
                return str(value)
            
            if role == QtCore.Qt.TextAlignmentRole:
                return QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter | QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter
                    
            if role == QtCore.Qt.ToolTipRole:
                return str(value)
        
    def rowCount(self, index=None):
        return self._data_source.shape[0]
    
    def columnCount(self, index=None):
        return self._data_source.shape[1]
    
    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole): 
        if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal and role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            if section < len(self._data_source.columns):
                return self._data_source.columns[section]
            
    def flags(self, index):
        return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable
    
    def setData(self, index, value, role):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole:
            try:
                value_as_float = float(value)
                if value_as_float.is_integer():
                    value_as_int = int(value_as_float)
                    self._data_source.iloc[index.row(), index.column()] = value_as_int
                else:
                    self._data_source.iloc[index.row(), index.column()] = value_as_float

            except ValueError:
                self._data_source.iloc[index.row(), index.column()] = value
            
            return True
            
    @property
    def data_source(self):
        return self._data_source
    
    @data_source.setter
    def data_source(self, data):
        if isinstance(data, dict):
            row = pd.DataFrame([data])

            self._data_source = pd.concat([self._data_source, row], ignore_index=True)

        if isinstance(data, pd.DataFrame):
            self._data_source = data

Thanks in advance!

Don't use start, as it's pointless since the argument is already an executable. Just do app.exe. If you still cannot get useful output, please [edit] your question and provide the contents of the spec file.

@musicamante when I only try urimare.exe (real app name) I got this error message: urimare.exe: The term 'urimare.exe' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
Suggestion [3,General]: The command "urimare.exe" was not found, but does exist in the current location.
PowerShell does not load commands from the current location by default (see ''Get-Help about_Command_Precedence'').

@musicamante done it! the .spec file was uploaded. I was investigating and the warn-main.text contains all the warnings pyinstaller found when running the main script to create the .exe file. Maybe could I find the answer in there? and, how can I search my problem in this file?

That error message is quite clear. Also, do not use PowerShell, use the standard command prompt: <win+r>, type "cmd" and press enter.

@musicamante wow thank you! runing from cmd now I can see what the error message is: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\isDev\OneDrive\Documents\PythonScripts\urimareApp\dist\urimare\_internal\qtstylish\compiled/dark.qss'.  What I dont understand is if when I run this program using python it works. Why now it says it does not found that file?

@musicamante I went to the dist folder to look for the file and I found that in the _internal folder there is no a qtstylish folder. Instead there is a qtstylish-0.1.5.dist-info folder but in there I can't find the folder compiled (following the path print in the error message)

@musicamante In my .spec file, in the Analisys block, I added the file as: (r".venv\Lib\site-packages\qtstylish\compiled", "qtstylish\compiled") and the last error disappear! Now I am facing another error: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "model\custom_table_model.py", line 27, in rowCount
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'. I posted the module custom_table_model. This problem must be another post?

We need a proper [mre]. If the issue only happens with the binary version, then you can update this post, otherwise you should consider closing this (as it's not reproducible) and create a more targeted one for the model issue.
